# How Can I echo this series 0110011001100110 in php

Tags: php, loops

```
0110011001100110

<?php

    $i = 0;
    $j = 1;

    for($k = 0; $k <= 10; $k++) {
        echo $i;    
        //**How Can I echo this series in php ::**      
        echo "<br/>";
    }

?>
```

Comment: I want output like this :
0110011001100110

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please add your current output and your expected output to your question. Also explain, where exactly you are stuck and need help

Comment: And also its pretty unclear what you want to do

Comment: @user3655429 what your method???

Comment: `echo implode('', array_fill(0, 4, '0110'));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try This
$i = 0;
$j = 1;
echo $i;
$flag = 1;  
$inc = 0;
for($k = 0; $k <= 10; $k++) {
    $inc++;
    if($flag == 0){
        echo $i;
        if($inc == 2){
            $flag = 1;
            $inc = 0;
        }
    }elseif($flag == 1){
        echo $j;
        //$flag = 0;
        if($inc == 2){
            $flag = 0;
            $inc = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For your help output should be Something like : even value,odd value,odd value,even value,even value,odd value,odd value, 1 1 0 0 1 1

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code.

It might help you.

```
echo "0";
for($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++)
{
    if($i % 2 == 0)
    {
        for($j = 1; $j <= 2; $j++)
        {
            echo "0";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for($j = 1; $j <= 2; $j++)
        {
            echo "1";
        }
    }
}
echo "0";
```

Comment: Hi there i dont want like this i need output like:
when first time loop run it echo 'even' and when loop run second time it echo 'odd' and when loop run third time it echo 'odd' and when loop run fourth time it echo 'even'

Comment: For your help output should be Something like :
even value,odd value,odd value,even value,even value,odd value,odd value,

1
1
0
0
1
1